# How to use explode for string and variable both?

Tags: php, explode

I have an variable like ****

I want to explode it.

I am using

```
$myVal= "C,6,11";
$garray = array_map('intval', explode(',', $myVal));
```

but i get  **0,6,11**

**i want C in-place of 0**. how it possible?

Comment: *intval — Get the integer value of a variable*.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the numbers to have an integer type in the resulting array you could try something like this:

```
$myVal= "C,6,11";
$garray = array_map(function($value) {
    if(strval($value) === strval(intval($value))) {
        return intval($value);
    } else {
        return $value;
    }
}, explode(',', $myVal));
```

however, if you don't care about the type you can just do that:

```
$myVal= "C,6,11";
$garray = explode(',', $myVal);
```